# HTML Master Page Error

Tags: custom-masterpage, sharepoint-on-prem

I am having this error after applying my master page, when I revert back to the Seattle Masterpage it works

> Sorry, something went wrong An error occurred during translation of
>   your HTML master page. For more information, please navigate to the
>   master page by clicking the preview button in the Master Page Gallery
>   or directly typing its URL. TECHNICAL DETAILS

Comment: perhaps a mistake by design like wrong place for an element? What does the Log say? What SharePoint version? 2013? How did u create the custom master?

Comment: Sharepoint version 2016, created the using html/ uploaded the folders(images, css). I can work on it as administrator when others get the error when trying to connect to the site

Comment: Did you publish a major version of your masterpage? 
Or did you insert elements the users have no permissions to?

Answer (score 0):

The masterpage I designed had some errors. To make things easier for me, I made a copy of Seattle.html; renamed it and it automatically created the .master(aspx)file. I re-branded to my taste. There was no error on my site and has been working perfectly fine